# Is this bad OO programming? Passing this down through methods

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, aggregation

Ok, assume I have a class, X and X is something which has an aggregate relationship with other objects. Lets pretend X is a soccer stadium.

X is full of class spectators. However, the behaviour of each spectator for a particular activity differs. Instead of IF statements, I want the different behaviour to be within the spectator class, so that I can use dynamic binding.

However, the problem is that the behaviour the spectator performs affects the "soccer stadium" class. So I was thinking of passing "this" from the soccer stadium class, through a method, to the Spectator class, so that the spectator class can do something to the Soccer Stadium class?

```
public class SoccerStadium{
    SpecatorInterface s = new Spectator();

    public void SpectatorBehaviour(){
        s.doSomething(this);
    }

    public void doSomethingthingBySpecator(){
    }
}

public class Spectator implements SpecatorInterface{
    public void doSomething(SoccerStadium s){
        s.doSomethingthingBySpecator();
    }
}
```

I only want to do this so that I can use dynamic binding and alter the behaviour in `Specator.doSomething()` so that I can have lots of different types of SpectatorSuperClass as an attribute passed to SoccerStadium and then have the different behaviour.

EDIT: What if I passed the reference of the Stadium to the Specator through the Spectator constructor, instead of passing `this`?

Comment: I believe purists will cringe at that technique because of the tight coupling, but it seems to be widely used. A "better" approach might be to create an interface that the stadium implements that defines what an outside entity can do to it and accept the stadium as that interface type in your spectator class.

Comment: How exactly does the specator affect soccer stadium? It seems to me that's a key point in determining the best type of relationship here.

Comment: @Esteban, very simple logic, setting attribute to values. Nothing heavy

Comment: @user997112: You've tagged this question as both `c#` and `java`.  Which is it?  If you're on C#, you can make use of [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx), which seem to fit your use case pretty nicely.

Comment: sorry did that as they're quite similar. this is for java. have untagged c#

Comment: Old question found via googling, but @itsme86 if you do as you say and abstract the spectator to an interface, it starts to look a lot like the Visitor pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is absolutely fine, I have seen that kind of thing before. Yes you can hold on to the Stadium reference, by passing it through the Spectator constructor, that would probably be cleaner than sending through the reference every time you need it.

However, I don't like it very much; I prefer inner classes. It's not completely clear what you're trying to do, but something like this is possible:

```
public class Outer {

private int someVariable=0;

public void someMethod(){
    ExtendsInner ei = new ExtendsInner();
    ei.innerMethod();
    System.out.println(someVariable);
}

private void anotherMethod(){
    someVariable++;
}

public abstract class Inner {
    public abstract void innerMethod();
}

public class ExtendsInner extends Inner{
    public void innerMethod(){
        anotherMethod();
        someVariable++;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Outer o = new Outer();
    o.someMethod();
}
}
```

Unfortunately, you would then have to have all of your "spectator" classes *inside* your other class, which could lead to one really long file, and thus, ugly code.

However, I think you should definitely avoid doing both things, as it will most definitely make your code overly complicated.

Comment: sorry, your right, it's not very clear. I was trying to say: don't use inner-classes and then put a reference to the outer class in the inner class. I have seen this done before, and I can think of no reason you would ever need to do this.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't so much "bad oo programming" as it is tightly [coupled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29). There's nothing inherently wrong with passing around `this` pointers, but it can become a mess very very quickly. We can't really say more without more information.

Comment: I am kinda trying to pass a method by pointer (as you would in C++) except I am using the dynamic binding via the Spectator interface, which is called by the stadium, to act upon the stadium.... I cant think of any other way.....

Comment: Just thought, what if instead of passing "this", I passed the reference of the Stadium to the Specator through the Spectator constructor?

Comment: @user997112 Does a `Spectator` often need to act on different `Stadium`s? If a `Spectator` is tied to a single `Stadium`, that would be a better solution.

Comment: @cklab, yes an instance of a Spectator is always tied to one instance of a Stadium

Answer (score 2):

I see no problem with the usage of this as a parameter. Nevertheless, I don't like the `new Spectator()` call that was hard coded in your `SoccerStadium` class. I believe you should have a Factory with a `createSpectator` method that could receive a parameter indicating which type of spectator you intend to create.

Comment: To be honest that was just something I quickly knocked up- I could pass the Spectator into the Stadium via the constructor, or, like my edit, I could do the reverse?

Comment: The point about my comment is that your code new Spectator() tightly couples the Stadium with a specific kind of Spectator. I was thinking that you could use the Factory pattern. Nevertheless, I think that you are probably going to have more than one spectator in each stadium, so you could have in Stadium a List (or another container) and an add method that would receive as parameter the SpectatorInterface. Afterwards, the Stadium could call doSomething(this).

Answer (score 2):

To me, this kind of two-way circular relationship is bad news. What if Spectators want to go to the Theatre instead?

I'd decouple the relationship by making the Stadium a subscriber to Spectator dispatched events.

```
public class SoccerStadium
{
    ISpectator s = new Spectator();
    public SoccerStadium()
    {
        s.DidSomething+=DoSomethingthingBySpecator;
    }
    public void SpectatorBehaviour()
    {
        s.DoSomething();
    }
    public void DoSomethingthingBySpecator(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("spectator did something");
    }
}
public interface ISpectator
{
    event EventHandler DidSomething;
    void DoSomething();
}
public class Spectator:ISpectator
{
    public event EventHandler DidSomething;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var ev=DidSomething;
        if(ev!=null)
        {
            ev(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

...and so the Spectator now has a means of communicating to anything that's interested, but doesn't need to know a thing about it.

Comment: See my edit concerning different Spectator 'containers'. I tend to build things so the small parts are not reliant on their containers. It serves me very well.

Comment: Could I be troublesome and ask for a code example (using mine if there's few edits to be done)?

Comment: @user997112 done (in c#, because that's what the original tags stated). You'll have to look around for Java equivalent. There's a bit more boilerplate in Java because IIRC you implement them with interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

As people have said, there's absolutely nothing wrong tight tight coupling and what you are doing.  However, if you want a little bit of decoupling, use the classic visitor pattern.

```
public interface SpectatorVisitor {
  ...
  void visit(Spectator spectator);
}

public class Spectator {
  ...
  public void accept(SpectatorVisitor visitor) {
      visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

public class Stadium {

  ...
  spectator.accept(new StadiumSpectatorVisitor());
}
```

The visit method signature could be altered to accept some kind of state object as well if you need to.  Otherwise you could simply define the relevant methods on the Spectator class, and make the visitor collect up the information needed to alter the stadium.

For instance:

```
public class Spectator {
  private Team supports;

  public Team getSupports() {
      return supports;
  }

  public void accept(SpectatorVisitor visitor) {
      visitor.visit(this);
  }
}

public class SupportedTeamVisitor {
  private Map<Team, AtomicLong> supportCount = new HashMap<Team, AtomicLong>();

  public void visit(Spectator spectator) {
     Team supports = spectator.getSupports();
     if (! supportCount.contains(supports)) {
       supportCount.put(team, new AtomicLong(0));
     }
     supports.get(team).incrementAndGet();
  }

  public Map<Team, AtomicLong> getSupportCount() {
     return supportCount;
  }
}


public class Stadium {

  public long getSupportCount(Team team) {
     SupportTeamVisitor visitor = new SupportedTeamVisitor();
     for (Spectator spectator : spectators) {
        spectator.accept(visitor);
     }
     AtomicLong count = visitor.getSupportCount().get(team);
     return (count == null) ? 0 : count.get();
  }
}
```

Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

As Matt said, what you are describing is the visitor pattern. Nevertheless, I don't think that's your best alternative (As Falmarri said, that kind of design tends to be tightly coupled, and you end up putting to much logic in your business object, breaking [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), etc..).
The fact that the behavior of each spectator for a particular activity differs, doesn't mean that the logic should be included (nor pass) through the spectator class. There are a lot of different ways to avoid those IF statements. I'd suggest you go with something like [this link](http://blogs.southworks.net/dgeffner/2011/09/26/implementing-complex-case-analysis/) suggest which is far more powerfull than the if statements, visitor pattern, or all the other alternatives, and it's really easy to implement it in another class, and maintain all those goods OOP principles (which are there for a reason).